# Android application crashes while trying to load a layout from a library project

Tags: android, crash, project

I have library project say LibProj which is having a layout file common.xml in that I am having a RelativeLayout with id relativeLayout1.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
```

In the App Project Activity class

```
public class AppStarter extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        setContentView(layout);
```

I have referenced the library project in the App project the eclipse IDE doesn't show any error but when I run the project in my device the application crashes.
I don't know what went wrong...?

Comment: 01-04 12:19:31.345: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(383): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060000 type #0x12 is not valid                                    This error comes when I try to use LayoutInflater instead of setContentView

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to use a LayoutInflater to inflate the "common.xml" before using it and finding it by id.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.common);
```

Something similar to that, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

layout in setContentView(layout) has to be the xml file name (e.g R.layout.common).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the Java package name of Android Library project

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) 
    findViewById(com.sample.library.R.id.relativeLayout1);
```

Another issue which will come up is if eclipse project has build automatically turned on, Library's R file will be replaced by Projects R file

Workaround : Disable build automatically and manually copy library project's resource file into the main project - in the appropriate folder

[image]

Comment: /home/administrator/Desktop/Screenshot.png

Comment: Try expanding the gen folder in your main project to make sure the R file in from library project

Answer (score 1):

you need create a folder named '**libs**' in the '**res**' folder, copy the library to '**libs**' folder

Comment: how is that going to help I mean there is no error in the class but still the application crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I have same kind of issue before: Reasons are

1) when you do

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
```

it do not know from where it should call your  relativeLayout1 , as it also can missmatch with ur application resources. as ID assign at run time.

Comment: before setting the setContentView